# Scala syntax for do-nothing function?

Tags: scala

Is there some standard way in Scala of specifying a function that does nothing, for example when implementing a trait? This works:

```
trait Doer {
  def doit
}

val nothingDoer = new Doer {
  def doit = { }
}
```

But perhaps there is some more congenial way of formulating nothingDoer?

**Edit** Some interesting answers have appeared, and I add a little to the question in response. First, it turns out that I could have used a default implementation in Doer. Good tip, but you don't always want that. Second, apparently a more idiomatic way of writing is:

```
val nothingDoer = new Doer {
  def doit { }
}
```

Third, although nobody suggested exactly that, I found that this also seems to work:

```
val nothingDoer = new Doer {
  def doit = Unit
}
```

Is this a good alternative?

(The ":Unit" that a few people suggested does not really add anything, I think.)

Comment: that is more like defining a trait, rather than implementing it

Comment: In response to your edit, I don't think `def doit = Unit` has any meaning. `Unit` is the singleton object of the `Unit` type. You might as well say `def doit = 42` or `def doit = ListBuffer`, because they work too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since your return type is Unit, it's conventional not to use the `=`

```
val nothingDoer = new Doer {
  def doit {}
}
```

Comment: Really? That wasn't my impression…

Comment: @njlarsson Ya rly. See http://www.codecommit.com/scala-style-guide.pdf section on method declarations

Comment: It's also a particularly un-conventional use case.  That "convention" is heavily based on the quite reasonable assumption that your method will actually contain some code, and is particularly ill-suited for this use case.  Besides which, the style *guide* only offers guidelines, not rigid dogma - you really want to be making the `Unit` return type much more explicit here, it far better self-documents the fact that you're doing something unusual and a bit silly.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a more idiomatic way of doing this (I don't think there is a equivalent of Python 'pass' i.e.).

But you can use "Unit" to specify that a method return nothing in a Trait:

```
def doit: Unit
```

Comment: Actually, this is the default, it makes no difference.

Comment: It make one in term of readability (and can be very important on classes), imho.

Comment: I was looking for a placeholder function syntax just like python's `pass`, not because I want functions that do nothing, but because I want to plan out functions & tests before implementing them, and have the project still compile so that `sbt console` etc still works. I know some of the type signatures for these so Unit doesn't work if I specify those. I could just use Unit and note my type signature in a TODO comment I guess. I'm probably just not being scala idiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

If you often have "do nothing" objects, you can also have "do nothing" as the default implementation:

```
trait Doer {
  def doit {}
}

val nothingDoer = new Doer
```

Answer (score 0):

Basicly you want something like:

```
trait Doer {
    def doit : Unit
}
```

You might consider looking at the type Option also.